# Why there's no "Create Test" Option when I click Alt + enter in my Maven Intellij project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, boot

I'm trying to implement a unit testing for my rest controller but when I click Alt + Enter
I can't see the create Test option
I tried to reinstall the dependencies, Invalid caches but it didn't work

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Which test framework do you use?

Comment: You project has not been imported correct. The source tree does not show that `src/main/java` has been identified as source code (different color blue). I recommend to close the project. Delete the `.idea` directoy as well as `*.iml` file and import the project from scratch....

Comment: I echo what khmarbaise said, but as far as I'm aware, you don't need to be so drastic to delete the .idea and *.iml files. Reimporting (refreshing) your Maven project from the Maven tab in IntelliJ should be sufficient.